# CKEditor - Change font family on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, ckeditor

Based on a JavaScript boolean, I need to change the `font-family` of `CKEditor` to `Meiryo`.

So far I have tried adding the following in my custom JS inside an `if` condition. But this doesn't change the `font-family`.

```
config.font_style =
{
    element     : 'span',
    styles      : { 'font-family' : '#Meiryo' },
    overrides   : [ { element : 'font', attributes : { 'face' : null } } ]
};
```

and also this in my custom script

```
config.font_defaultLabel = 'Meiryo';
config.fontSize_defaultLabel = '12px';
```

None of them worked. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check you js console for errors.

Comment: this answer may be found useful:
<br>
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66633660/13266927

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is:

```
config.font_style =
    {
        element     : 'span',
        styles      : { 'font-family' : '#(Meiryo)' },
        overrides   : [ { element : 'font', attributes : { 'face' : null } } ]
    };
```

rather than:

```
config.font_style =
{
    element     : 'span',
    styles      : { 'font-family' : '#Meiryo' },
    overrides   : [ { element : 'font', attributes : { 'face' : null } } ]
};
```

All accepted:

```
145 CKEDITOR.config.font_names =
146     'Arial/Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
147     'Comic Sans MS/Comic Sans MS, cursive;' +
148     'Courier New/Courier New, Courier, monospace;' +
149     'Georgia/Georgia, serif;' +
150     'Lucida Sans Unicode/Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, sans-serif;' +
151     'Tahoma/Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;' +
152     'Times New Roman/Times New Roman, Times, serif;' +
153     'Trebuchet MS/Trebuchet MS, Helvetica, sans-serif;' +
154     'Verdana/Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif';
```

From:

http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.font_style